# Fill mongoDB with Fixtures data from symfony 3.2

Tags: mongodb, symfony, php-mongodb

I'm working on a Symfony project, and I'm trying to fill some fixtures data to mongoDB, that's what I did :

```
<?php

namespace FrontOfficeBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use FrontOfficeBundle\Document\Customer;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class Fixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->setName("Ben Abdallah");
        $customer->setSurename("Wajdi");
        $customer->setUsername("wajdibenabdallah");
        $customer->setEmail("wajdi.benabdallah@smarttouchtunisie.com");
        $customer->setPhone("28812010");
        $customer->setPassword("");

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

> php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:fixtures:load

and then i got back these results :

```
Careful, database will be purged. Do you want to continue (y/N) ?y
  > purging database
  > loading Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\EmptyFixture
  > loading FrontOfficeBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\Fixtures
```

But nothing has happened in the database (still empty).

I'am using :

- ubuntuu 16.04
- Symfony 3.2
- MongoDB 3.4.4
- PHP 7.0.23

**Any ideas ?**
Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to persist the `$customer` object:

```
$manager->persist($customer);   // Store in database.
```

Can you try that?